# Backup for a linux system via osx

Tags: linux, macos, embedded-linux, macos-catalina, cp

I have an odroid (raspberry-like) machine with an arch linux system installed. Now I want to move the system from one microsd (A) to another microsd (B). When I tried this, the system became corrupted, information about files attributes were lost:

1. Copy files from A to osx-host `cp -R /Volume/microsd_a/* ~/Desktop/backup`
2. Copy files from osx-host to B `cp -R ~/Desktop/backup/* /Volume/microsd_b`

Is it real to copy linux-system using osx-host with preserving integrity?

**Update:**

1. `dd`. I tried this way, but there is a problem. My sd cards have different sizes, 64 Gb and 16 Gb, but system installed on 64 Gb disk has no more than 8 Gb. So when I launched the copying process, output image file exceed 16 Gb and I killed the process. By the way, the MBR contains information about partition table which should be different (one partition 64Gb / one partition 16 gb). And notice, I do **not** need to copy bootloader from MBR, I have an ability to flash disk bootloader by other ways.
2. `cp`. What I wanted to listen as the answer is the list of flags I need to make this operation. Reading `man cp` didn't help me. `cp -a` does not copy all files because of `Cannot allocate memory` error. Tried `cp -aX`, no attributes were restored after copying data to second sdcard.
3. `tar`. I tried multiple times with flags, last one was `tar -cvpf; tar --same-owner -xpf`. But file attributes were still corrupted.

Again:
- Are you sure, it is possible to preserve file attributes through copying `ext4 -> APFS -> ext4`?
- If this is possisble, how does it work and which command with which flags should I use?

Answer (score 1):

`cp -R` results in change of permissions, time stamps and missing of hidden files, you can't use that command to create a disk image.

what you need is a disk copy/clone. The command to use is `dd`.

Check out this webpage:

https://pbxbook.com/other/dd_clone.html

Comment: `man cp` It may preserve a lot of stuff, and `dd` has its own disadvantages. `tar` OTOH is more generic, but also has pros and cons.

Comment: commands like `cp -a` or `rsync -tav` keep file properties, but they don't preserve byte order, partition tables or MBR. The only way to get those cloned is to use a byte-copy utility, such as `dd`.

Comment: Byte order?! What do you mean?

Comment: what I meant was raw sector-by-sector information. Some files are not stored on contiguous sectors. `dd` maps sector-level data but `cp/rsync` won't.